# How to keep track of pip installed packages on one docker container to use them in another

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

i'm trying to get involved in docker magic and there is a question:
I want to run container in which installed all python packages and after up of this "source" container run my python script that uses those installed on first docker container packages?
I have one dockerfile in which I have installed python3 and pip and in docker-compose.yml file i am building all requirments in first container

How to update docker-compose.yml file to make second container be able to use all installed on another container packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/) and docker volumes.

In one image build  a virtualenv and make it a volume:

```
RUN virtualenv /venv
RUN /venv/bin/pip install ...
VOLUME /venv
```

And for the second container use `volumes_from: ['the-first-container']`

You might not need the virtualenv if you want to just make the default python site-packages path a `VOLUME`.

Answer (score 3):

use `pip freeze` to get a list of all installed pip packages along with their specific versions. Standard practice is to keep a text file `requirements.txt` for pip installations.

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt

$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

add this line to your docker file:

```
ONBUILD RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
```

Comment: I want to instsall requirements once in one container and use them in another

Comment: @DmitryMarkovnikov Then create and push one image with the dependencies and use this as a base image for other images. However, I think you're overthinking this. Docker will create a layer for each line in the Docker file. The pip install results will only be stored once.